# Odd event handler error: num.toString is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

An odd problem. Hard to describe in few words, but I'll try. (I am a JavaScript beginner).

When a mouse hovers over a `.u` tag, I want it to do something. So I have:

```
var dotUElements = document.getElementsByClassName("u");

for (var ii = 0; ii < dotUElements.length; ii++) {
    dotUElements[ii].onmouseover = createHandler1( dotUElements[ii] );
    dotUElements[ii].onmouseout = createHandler2( dotUElements[ii] );
}
```

then adding handlers:

```
function createHandler1( myobj ) {
    return (function() {ff1(myobj);});
}

function createHandler2( myobj ) {
    return (function() {ff2(myobj);});
}
```

my functions `ff1` for `mouseover` and `ff2` for mouse out are:

```
function ff1 (myobj) {
    myobj.style.color="red";
    var uChar = myobj.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var uNum =  uChar.charCodeAt(0);
    uName = unicodeTable(uNum);
    var uHex = (uNum).toSring(16);
}

function ff2 (myobj) {
    myobj.style.color="black";
}
```

the problem is the last line

```
    var uHex = (uNum).toSring(16);
```

it creates error:

> Error: TypeError: uNum.toSring is not a function

if I replace that line by simply

```
(30).toSring(16);
```

same error. Any hints on what's wrong? I have the code at

http://xahlee.info/js/ex/xx_test.html

Comment: it should be toString

Comment: darn. spent a hour on this. Something wrong with my template system it inserts Sring... thx @harsha

Comment: or maybe , your template system doesn't recognize 't' ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working demo for your example

```js
function unicodeTable(num) {
  var unicodedata = {
    0x2190: "LEFTWARDS ARROW",
    0x2191: "UPWARDS ARROW",
    0x2192: "RIGHTWARDS ARROW",
    0x2193: "DOWNWARDS ARROW",
  };
  return unicodedata[num];
}

function createHandler1(myobj) {
  return (function() {
    ff1(myobj);
  });
}

function createHandler2(myobj) {
  return (function() {
    ff2(myobj);
  });
}

function ff1(myobj) {
  myobj.style.color = "red"; // test code. so we know it's activated
  var uChar = myobj.firstChild.nodeValue;
  var uNum = uChar.charCodeAt(0);
  uName = unicodeTable(uNum);
  var uHex = (uNum).toString(16);
  alert(uHex);
}

function ff2(myobj) {
  myobj.style.color = "black"; // test code. so we know it's activated
}

var dotUElements = document.getElementsByClassName("u");

for (var ii = 0; ii < dotUElements.length; ii++) {
  dotUElements[ii].onmouseover = createHandler1(dotUElements[ii]);
  dotUElements[ii].onmouseout = createHandler2(dotUElements[ii]);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>unicode test 3</h1>

  <p>
    <b class="u">←</b>
    <b class="u">→</b>
    <b class="u">↑</b>
    <b class="u">↓</b>
  </p>

  <p>when mouse hover on b.u element, show the unicode name.</p>
</body>
```

I have added an `alert(uHex);` to show the value.

Let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: @Hill : FYI, the OP accepted the answer and he/she did so since they understood what I meant! Problem?

Comment: Oh, well I guess that just completely removes the idea that someone would come along and ask a duplicate question, doesn't it Harsha Venkabashaboopie?

Comment: @Hill : LOL , you sound like a kid, calling names. Peace dude :D